# Java for Mobile and Desktop Development

Tags: java, javafx

I took several courses and learned the basic syntax of Java. I'm wondering which Java tools should I study if I want to develop desktop and mobile applications?

I'm learning javafx now. Is this primarily used for desktop development or will it help me in Mobile Android development as well?If not, what should I look in to? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at RoboVM: http://robovm.com/

Yet, JavaFX isn't the best solution for mobile app development, in my opinion. Java is perfect for Android, though.

Regarding desktop development, JavaFX is really appropriate (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, with a nice feature for self-deployment packages (using Inno Setup on Windows, and creating native .dmg package on Mac OS X)).

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure javaFX is widely used on mobile development, it can be made.

[Here's an example in android](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications)

Since you're a begginner, you could study a bit of awt and swing.